# ssl certificate was not renewed

Tags: ssl, swisscomdev

My swisscom cloud foundry service is not available anymore because the SSL certificate was not automatically renewed. I even cannot turn off the certificate, it says that a running process of type "RENEW" exists. How can I renew the certificate? Why is this not done automatically?

Comment: If you renewed the certificate manually then you probably need to perform a verification over your domain.

Comment: I also cannot renew the certificate manually, this is my problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to various reasons the certification renewal process can fail and in some cases an automatic recover is not possible. Please contact Swisscom's Developer Support and give them the ORG, SPACE and domain affected. They will sort this out for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to contact Swisscom over the following link https://developer.swisscom.com/support but I still got still no answer. Very bad service from Swisscom...

Comment: Usually they answer quite fast but the SLA on the public offering is 'best effort', so sometimes it takes a bit longer.